# What is the difference between override and extend in Java?

Tags: java

`final` keyword can be used with  method and class, but if we used it with method then method can't be override and if we used it with class then it can not be extend means?  For that please let me know what is main difference between override and extend?

For example below program give compilation error(Compile time error):

```
Class Bike{  
  final void run(){
    System.out.println("running");
  }  
}  

class Honda extends Bike{  
   void run(){
      System.out.println("running safely with 100kmph");
   }  

   public static void main(String args[]){  
   Honda honda= new Honda();  
   honda.run();  
   }  
}
```

Comment: Calm down, format. Then ask for help.

Comment: Duh. `lass Bike`. It won't work

Comment: `title.toLowerCase();`

Comment: You're looking for the documentation.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ it's ironic that your name is in all caps ;)

Comment: What's the compilation error?  Post a stack trace please.

Comment: @Samuel lol. Not that much as OP's :P

Answer (score 0):

1. INDENT THE CODE! AND FIX THE FORMATTING ISSUES!

```
lass Bike {
    final void run() {
        System.out.println("running");
    }
}

class Honda extends Bike {
    void run() {
        System.out.println("running safely with 100kmph");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Honda honda = new Honda();
        honda.run();
    }
}
```

2. Fix the class declaration:

```
class Bike {
    final void run() {
        System.out.println("running");
    }
}

class Honda extends Bike {
    void run() {
        System.out.println("running safely with 100kmph");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Honda honda = new Honda();
        honda.run();
    }
}
```

3. The `final` keyword on a method means that it **cannot** be overridden, meaning this:

For example, I have a class `Dog`:

```
public class Dog {
    final void bark() {
        System.out.println("Woof!");
    }
}
```

And I have a wolf:

```
class Wolf extends Dog {

}
```

The `Wolf` class **cannot** override the `bark` method, meaning that no matter what, it prints `Woof!`. However, this might be what you want:

```
class Bike {
    void run() {
        System.out.println("running");
    }
}

class Honda extends Bike {
    @Override
    void run() {
        System.out.println("running safely with 100kmph");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Honda honda = new Honda();
        honda.run();
    }
}
```